# How to shift chars w/pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to write a function in C which shifts each letter of a `char *`, so `'a'` becomes `'z'` and `'b'` becomes `'y'`. In the `if` statements below, it's my understanding that `(*p - 'a')` is the letter `p` points to, but I'm not sure how to shift the char to achieve the desired result. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
void encode(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *p, *q;

    q = s2;
    for (p = s1; p < p + p[STR_LEN]; p++, q++) {
        if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z') {
            *q = (*p - 'a');
        } else
        if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') {
            *q = (*p - 'A');
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the help! It looks like the best algorithm was *q = 'A' + 'Z' - (*p), but for some reason it's only encoding the first and second word, with this ▒ as a space. The problem is obviously the rest of my code so I'll get to work. Thanks again!

**EDIT2**

I had to add the code below to account for a space character. Thanks again!

```
else if (*p == ' ')
            {
                    *q = ' ';
            }
```

Comment: 'a' => 'z' and 'b' => 'y' seems more like a reflection than a shift. Which is it?

Comment: John, I'm not sure what reflection is but this function is suppose to encode a char string. The shift, if each letter was labeled 0 -25, would be 25 - i.

Comment: `-- For each lowercase basic latin letter, using the character codes as a number line, see how far it is from 'a', then start at 'z' and go back that same distance. Similarly for uppercase.`

Comment: The test `p < p + p[STR_LEN]` is most likely incorrect.

Comment: chqrlie, yes that was an incorrect use of STR_LEN. I am now using the null character.

Comment: @bambaera "reflection" means that the order of the letters is *reversed*. Shift is something like 'a' => 'z', 'b' => 'a', 'c' => 'b', ..., 'z' => 'y'. Such a transformation (called a *Caesar shift*) is the standard meaning of the word "shift" in classical cryptography.

Comment: Ah understood, thanks John!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulae are incorrect:

- your test for end of string is bizarre, you should probably just check for the `'\0'` terminator.
- you must subtract the difference from the character to `a`, from `z`.
- you should also copy the characters that are not letters.
- you should set a null terminator at the end of the destination string.

Here is a modified version:

```
void encode(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *p, *q;

    for (p = s1, q = s2; *p != '\0'; p++, q++) {
        if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z') {
            *q = 'z' - (*p - 'a');
        } else
        if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') {
            *q = 'Z' - (*p - 'A');
        } else {
            *q = *p;
        }
    }
    *q = '\0';
}
```

Note that this programs assumes that all lowercase and uppercase characters are consecutive, which is true for ASCII but false for EBCDIC.

Here is a alternate version that performs a generic substitution, for all character sets:

```
char const source_set[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char const mirror_set[] = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";

void encode(const char *src, char *dest) {
    for (; *src; src++, dest++) {
        const char *p = strchr(source_set, *src);
        *dest = p ? mirror_set[p - source_set] : *src;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

Note that the order of the arguments is inconsistent with common practice, rooted in the standard library examples: `strcpy`, `memcpy` and many others pass the destination before the source arrays.

Here is another solution for 8-bit characters that requires an initialization step but produces a very efficient encoding function:

```
char const source_set[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char const mirror_set[] = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
char encode_array[256];

void encode_initialize(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        encode_array[i] = (char)i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; source_set[i]; i++) {
        encode_array[(unsigned char)source_set[i]] = mirror_set[i];
    }
}

void encode(const char *src, char *dest) {
    while ((*dest++ = encode_array[(unsigned char)*src++]) != '\0')
        continue;
}
```

Comment: The generic solution also has the advantage of being clearly what the requirements state. I would use it unless it took more than a screenful of code to set up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this  `*q = (*p - 'a');`

Look whats happening! Imagine `*p` is 'c'. `*q` then becomes 99-97=2 i.e. character value of *ASCII 2*. Instead it should have ASCII value of **120** i.e. x.

So use plain Arithmetic with ASCII values. This would result in

```
*q='a'+'z'-(*p);//97+122-99=120 for *p='c'
```

Similarly for A-Z range

```
*q='A'+'Z'-(*p);
```

So the code would look like this:

```
void encode(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *p, *q;

    q = s2;
    p=s1;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<STR_LEN; i++) {// I am assuming that STR_LEN is a macro or global value.
        if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z') {
            *q='a'+'z'-(*p);
        } else if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') {
            *q='A'+'Z'-(*p);
        }else {
            *q=*p;
        }
        p++;
        q++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Vidor, thank you for commenting. I should have clarified that the code was incomplete. I had actually tested (*p - 'a') to see what he got me. Also forgot to mention that yes, STR_LEN is a macro but another user suggested I use the null character, which makes more sense. However, I want to use pointers instead of subscripting since pointers are pretty useful in C. So far your code has worked the best, but it only shifts the first word or two. FOr instance, Input: The wall is falling / Output: Gsv;dzoo. Gsv correctly transforms "The" but I'm not sure about ;dzoo

Comment: @bambaera I was skeptical about that STR_LEN thing. The best I could assume was that it was the length of s2. You can go either way, checking for null or looping for length less than that of the string. But the main logic was that formula.

Comment: `*q` is not set in all branches!

Comment: @TomBlodget Sorry man, I don't understand what you mean! Elaborate so I can update or send me an edit

Comment: The goal of the loop body is to set *q. In case where *p is neither an uppercase or lowercase basic Latin letter, your code doesn't achieve the goal.

Comment: Updated! I missed that simple case.!

Answer (score 1):

```
*q = ('z' - *p) + 'a';
```

It likes number 0 becomes number 25 and number 25 becomes number 0.

Comment: Thanks Cwift, I actually ended up using *q='A'+'Z'-(*p).

Answer (score 0):

See the following code. It shifts all the letters as per your need.
'a' becomes 'z', 'A' becomes 'Z', 'b' becomes 'y' and 'B' becomes 'Y' etc...

Note: here I am assuming s1 is the letter to be shift and result goes in s2.

```
void encode(char *s1, char *s2) {
    if ((*s1 >= 'a') && (*s1 <= 'z')) {
        *s2 = 'z' - (*s1 - 'a');
    } else if ((*s1 >= 'A') && (*s2 <= 'Z')) {
        *s2 = 'Z' - (*s1 - 'A');
    }
}
```